# draw a graph using Mpandroid chart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I want to draw a line chart with MPAndroidChart, but when I want to set line data I get this error:

> LineData (com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet...) in LineData cannot be applied to
>   (java.util.ArrayList, com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet)

[image: a picture of the error message in IDE]

Answer (score 0):

At present, there is no constructor that accepts `List<string>`,`LineDataSet`. The available constructors are:

```
public LineData() {
    super();
}

public LineData(ILineDataSet... dataSets) {
    super(dataSets);
}

public LineData(List<ILineDataSet> dataSets) {
    super(dataSets);
}
```

You can read the entire class definition [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/d7e659a1fac34f1d187d2ac259a415302ba2cadf/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineData.java).

You need to set the x-values differently. [This](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/d7e659a1fac34f1d187d2ac259a415302ba2cadf/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartTime.java) example might help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
xAxis.setTextSize(10f);
date.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    date.add("第" + i + "天");


}
//Set the X axis below the data (not the same as the previous version)

xAxis.setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        axis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
        axis.resetAxisMaxValue();
        axis.isAxisMaxCustom();
        int a = (int) value;

        return date.get(a);//  Data below
    }

    @Override
    public int getDecimalDigits() {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Maybe it will help you

Comment: Kindly provide little more explanation for your answer

Comment: Even translating the code comments to English would be a huge help.